# react-select UTF encoding makes 'x' look like 'Ã—' multiselect

Tags: javascript, css, utf-8, react-select

I am using the react-select, 1.0.0-beta14 component, installed via npm.

I have a selector in a stateless functional component:

```
        <ControlLabel>Days Of Week</ControlLabel>
        <Select
            onChange={props.dayOfWeekOnChange}
            name="dayOfWeekSelector"
            value={props.dayOfWeek}
            multi={true}
            options={props.daysOfWeek.map(function (dayOfWeek, i) {
                return { value: dayOfWeek, label: dayOfWeek }
            }) }>
        </Select>
```

When I make selections in it, the little 'x' shows up as 'Ã—'. I'm including the css file via require and processing it with "css-loader": "^0.23.1" via webpack.

[This site](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) led me to believe it might be an encoding problem, but I'm not sure where to look to fix this.

their example:

[image]

mine:

[image: multiselect with weird characters]

Comment: Looks like this is happening all over the place in my code. I'm also seeing it in the close 'x' for my react-bootstrap modal.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>`tag of your main html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had the same issue and solved it by adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` tag of your main html file. – Moltes

This solved my problem.